# usermod www-data group mistake

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I have an amazon AWS server setup and while trying to get write permissions working I executed this command from an article I found while logged in to the server

```
sudo usermod -G ubuntu www-data
```

Now I can't see the public website. How do I undo what I have done??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to use the `-a` switch to usermod so it just changed the supplementary group of www-data to ubuntu and then removed www-data from all other supplementary groups. You will need to add the www-data account back into the relevant supplementary groups

```
usermod -a -G <group1>, <group2> ...
```

> -G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
>              A list of supplementary groups which the user is also a member of.
>              Each group is separated from the next by a comma, with no
>              intervening whitespace. The groups are subject to the same
>              restrictions as the group given with the -g option.
>
> If the user is currently a member of a group which is not listed,
>              the user will be removed from the group. This behaviour can be
>              changed via the -a option, which appends the user to the current
>              supplementary group list

Comment: thanks Iain - do you know what groups www-data is supposed to belong to?

Comment: @sube1even: I would try www-data and beyond that I wouldn't know.

Comment: Thanks Iain it is just www-data. And my permissions were incorrect for /var/www - so now it's working again. Probably a simple question but you helped.